# Java 7, color of button text when using HTML formatted labels

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, java-7

I have a custom UI for certain buttons, implemented by subclassing MetalButtonUI. The buttons use HTML-formatted labels. This is a requirement for me, I need to support multiline button labels.

For some reason, when my application runs on Java 7 (scientifically update 4, the most current) the text color when the button is disabled is now grey. This does not happen when running on Java 4 or 6.

In the HTML for the button label, I can set the font color by using `<font color=..>` However this value is ignored when the button is disabled. It seems like somewhere, my font color is overridden when the button is disabled. Using `<body style='color: ..'>` is also ineffective.

I've tried setting Button.disabledText in UIDefaults. This isn't what I really want to do because it affects too many buttons. But in any case it isn't effective for HTML formatted button labels.

MetalButtonUI defines getDisabledTextColor, but implementing it is not effective.

Similarly, implementing the paintText method is not effective. It is not invoked for HTML-formatted labels.

I could override the entire paint method but that seems like an overly complex solution.

There was a bugfix in this area, reported fixed in Java 7, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4783068 The bug report isn't very clear to me however. It isn't clear what specifically was changed, or how to override the new behavior.

Does anyone know how to control the text color for disabled buttons?

EDIT: Sorry I should have included example code from the get-go. My original code had custom classes for the button and for the UI, with custom paint() methods in the UI class. But I now see that the core problem can be demonstrated very simply, with just a call to button.setForeground(Color.black); In Java 6 this affects the text color for both enabled and disabled states. In Java 7 it affects only the enabled state.  mKorbel ... thank you for helping isolate the problem!!!!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    
    public class DisabledButtonDemo {
    
        
        public DisabledButtonDemo() {
            final JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(
               "<html><center>Button<br/>Label</center></html>");      
    
            // Next line sets the text color. 
            // In Java 6 it is respected, for both enabled and disabled state.
            // In Java 7, it is only used for the enabled state.
            button.setForeground(Color.black); 
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            
            final JButton controlButton = new JButton(
               "Toggle Enabled/Disabled");
            controlButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button.setEnabled(!button.isEnabled());
                }
            });
            
            JFrame f = new JFrame("ButtonTest");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
            f.add(button);
            f.add(controlButton);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DisabledButtonDemo t = new DisabledButtonDemo();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Edit #2: this is now tracked as a bug by Oracle, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7176683

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with MetalButtonUI inc overriden methods (better would be BasicButtonUI), Java7 and Html syntax

Comment: Could be the look and feel of Java7 is ignoring the coloring of while in disabled state.

Comment: Yes Java 7 is behaving differently. I've filed a bug report with Oracle, will post URL if I get one.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how to control the text color for disabled buttons?

one of the way (you meant Html) is

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HtmlAndJButton {

    public HtmlAndJButton() {
        final String buttonText = " Whatever, but nothing wise";
        final JButton button = new JButton(buttonText);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Toggle");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setText("<html><font color=" + (button.isEnabled() ? "blue" : "red") + ">"
                + buttonText + "</font></html>");
                button.setEnabled(!button.isEnabled());
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ButtonTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        f.add(button);
        f.add(btn1);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                HtmlAndJButton t = new HtmlAndJButton();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This example code exactly demonstrates the problem! When run on Java 6, the text color toggles between red and blue as desired. When run on Java 7, it toggles between red and gray (or maybe blue/gray).

Answer (score 0):

I read the bug report that you posted on your question and they provided a workaround that will solve this issue. Create the below class:

```
/**
 * Attaches to a JButton to work around Sun bug 4783068.
 * <p>http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4783068</p>
 */
public final class SunBug4783068Fixer implements PropertyChangeListener {

private static final SunBug4783068Fixer INSTANCE = new SunBug4783068Fixer();

public static void attach(AbstractButton to) {
    // Prevents adding it more than once to any single component.
    to.removePropertyChangeListener(INSTANCE);

    to.addPropertyChangeListener(INSTANCE);
}

public static void remove(AbstractButton from) {
    from.removePropertyChangeListener(INSTANCE);
}

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if ((evt.getSource() instanceof AbstractButton)
         && "enabled".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
        AbstractButton target = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();
        target.setForeground(target.isEnabled()
            ? (Color) UIManager.getDefaults().get("Button.foreground")
            : (Color) UIManager.getDefaults().get("Button.disabledText"));
    }
  }
}
```

Then add it to your JToggleButton like so

```
 final JButton controlButton = new JButton("Toggle Enabled/Disabled");
        controlButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setEnabled(!button.isEnabled());
            }
        });
 controlButton.addPropertyChangeListener(new SunBug4783068Fixer());
```

Comment: This works, in Java 6. But in Java 7, the text color remains Gray. There is something very strange going on which only occurs when running on the Java 7 JRE. The call to target.setForeground is simply not effective, it is getting overridden somewhere.

Comment: You could read the bug report and try out all the different work-arounds people have posted. Try not using html in the toggle button. You are only using it to center the text, you can do that with regular java `setHorizontalAlignment(JToggleButton.CENTER)`

Comment: re: Try not using html in the toggle button. .... I need HTML because I need multiline button labels.

Comment: re: You could read the bug report and try out all the different work-arounds people have posted..... with one paint-related exception, the work-arounds are all different ways to invoke setForeground dynamically, or change the HTML dynamically. The last post on that bug report was October 2008, while Java 7 came out July 2011. (I included that old bug report b/c I suspected it might be related. But I should probably should have pointed out that it is very old, pre-Java 7.)